# Smart Object Layer Visibility with Layer Comps

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject

I wanted to create a set of layer comps but ran into a problem when trying to toggle the visibility of layers within a smart object. Let's say I have a document with smart object. I want 1/5 layers visible for each of my 5 layer comps (each layer having its own comp).

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way I can get both the original document and smart object to work together in terms of displaying the desired smart object layers. One possible reason is that they work independently from each other (psd & psb). Its almost like they are two separate (yet connected) documents but with two different layer comp panels. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I don't understand. You're toggling visibility *within* the Smart Object?

Comment: Yea. The visibility of layers within a smart object.

Comment: As you've discovered, you can't do that. You need individual Smart Objects (New Smart Object via copy) and then toggle the inner visibility on the new SO... and use the new SO in the Comp. And yes, file size will increase.

Comment: Dear Adobe, plz fix this.